# Implementing phone call service in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm new to Xamarin. I have a Xamarin Forms App which needs to implement the phone call service for ios and android.

This is my Interface under the .net shared proj:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace CallMeMaybe.Services
{
   public interface ICallService
  {
     void MakePhoneCall(string number);
  }
}
```

This is the command method in the view model:

```
   private void OnCall(object s)
    {
        DependencyService.Get<ICallService>().MakePhoneCall(Convert.ToString(s));
    }
```

This is my Android Call Service that needs to implement the MakePhoneCall method

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using CallMeMaybe.Droid.Services;
using CallMeMaybe.Services;
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(CallService))]
namespace CallMeMaybe.Droid.Services
{
    [Activity(Label = "CallService")]
    public class CallService : ICallService
    {

        public void MakePhoneCall(string number)
        {

            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + number);
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall, uri);
            //Start Activity here?

        }
    }
}
```

How can I start the dial activity in my Android Method? This is a service class not an Activity class so I'm not extending Activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all this class is not an activiry, so you need to remove `[Activity(Label = "CallService")]`

```
    public void MakePhoneCall(string number)
    {
        var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall, Android.Net.Uri.Parse(
                                                              "tel:" + Uri.EscapeDataString(phoneNumber)));
        Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
    }
```

This intent will open calling app and start call

By executing `StartActivity(intent)` you command Android to open Calling App Activity and start call

Answer (score 0):

Working fine now. Use the Application Context to start the activity

```
 public void MakePhoneCall(string number)
    {
        var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse("tel:" + number);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall, uri);
        intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
        Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
    }
```